# Conditional tracking

Tags: conditionals

I want to exclude my site's tracking code(s) from my local development templates, but I've a hard time writing the conditional.

I am using an embedded template which contains the doctype, metadata and also has an embed for the css template.

Could you write a conditional within this embedded template which checks if there is a file (snipped or embedded template)  called "analysis"?

Comment: Need more information. Tracking codes - is this EE page tracking or Google Analytics (or similar)? What's a snipped template - do you mean snippet variable? Please confirm that the file you're checking for is a template file (which could surely be database too) or another external file unrelated to EE.

Answer (score 1):

using my bootstrapped config file http://d.pr/n/tTcT I create a global variable for the particular environment I'm working in and then in my template code I do

```
{if gv_env == 'prod'}
my analytics tracking code
{/if}
```